# Centering wide supertabular tables with \makebox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, page-breaking, supertabular

I am trying to use `\makebox` to center a wide `\supertabular` table, but if the table spans more than one page, latex gives a `! Missing \endgroup inserted`.
Any ideas on how to center a wide `supertable`?

Here is an example, which works fine if you remove a line so that the table fits on one page:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{supertabular}

\begin{document}

\tablehead{
\hline \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
}

\tabletail{
\hline \hline
}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{supertabular}{ c c c c c c}
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
\end{supertabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Also, the captions for `supertable` seem to have problems, including a `\tablecaption` results in `! Missing \endgroup inserted`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{supertabular}

\begin{document}

\tablehead{
\hline \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
}

\tabletail{
\hline \hline
}

 \tablecaption{example table}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{supertabular}{ c c c c c c}
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
\end{supertabular}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Answer (score 4):

You do not want to use a box as that by definition will not break over a page.

Normally you could just use `\centering`  but first you need to make the text width wider than the content, so centering works (you would need this for any centering, not just for the table)  The `outdent` environment here is just a copy of `quote` but decreases rather than increases the margin, and adds `\centering`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{supertabular}

\newenvironment{outdent}
{\begin{list}{}{\leftmargin-2cm\rightmargin\leftmargin}\centering\item\relax}
{\end{list}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\tablehead{
\hline \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
}

\tabletail{
\hline \hline
}


\noindent X \dotfill X

\begin{outdent}

\noindent X \dotfill X


\begin{supertabular}{ c c c c c c }
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
AAAAAAAAAA & BBBBBBBBBB & DDDDDDDDDDD & EEEEEEEEEE & FFFFFFFFFF \\
\end{supertabular}
\end{outdent}

\end{document}
```