# Margins on a minipage

Tags: margins, minipage

I have a formula which very nearly fits on one line, and I'd like it to sit on one line as it looks silly split onto two.

If I reduce the left and right margins for the whole document to 1cm, the long formula fits on one line but the rest of the document looks strange.

Is there any way to set the margins for just that one line to 1cm, while keeping the rest of the document at 2.5cm. Such as using a minipage?

Comment: Here's a solution: [Center over-long equations between both margins](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156877/5764)

Comment: you don't need a minipage just a list env eg `outdent` from here (which is just the standard `quote` environment, with some signs changed) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128047/centering-wide-supertabular-tables-with-makebox/128056#128056

Comment: warning: if this is to be published, the specified margins *must* be observed, since a wider line can be either "lost" in the binding, or cut off at the outer trim, and reducing the margins for this line by 60% is asking for trouble.  you might consider using smaller size type for the wide formula, or scaling it as a unit, although either of those approaches should be considered only as a last resort.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `\hspace{-2mm}` and try different values (+ / -) until it will look good.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.